# WL6.1 Deploying sql adapter with dataSourceJNDIName give error Runtime: Datasource not found in jndi

Tags: websphere, ibm-mobilefirst

i am deploying an sql adapter on was liberty 8.5.5. i'm trying to connect to the APPCNTR database installed with WL. 
the datasource name declared in server.xml :

```
  <dataSource jndiName="jdbc/AppCenterDS" transactional="false">
         <jdbcDriver libraryRef="MySQLLib"/>
         <properties URL="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/APPCNTR" user="ibmappcenter" password="xxxx"/>
    </dataSource>
```

the adapter xml :

```
<connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="sql:SQLConnectionPolicy">
                <dataSourceJNDIName>java:comp/env/jdbc/AppCenterDS</dataSourceJNDIName>
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="5" />
     </connectivity>
```

the error in javascript console : Runtime: Datasource java:comp/env/jdbc/AppCenterDS not found in jndi
what is the correct syntax ? 
do i miss something while deploying the application? 
thanks for your help
regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that the generated files has

```
<dataSourceJNDIName>java:/data-source-jndi-name</dataSourceJNDIName>
```

as the model, but I've never been able to get that to work.  It should work with the simple name:

```
<dataSourceJNDIName>jdbc/AppCenterDS</dataSourceJNDIName>
```